# SharePoint SPFX React pnp listview control issue with responsiveness

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, pnp-js

I am using pnp listview control in my SharePoint SPFX and currently adding this control to view few items from sharepoint online list.

It is working fine however, its behavior is not responsive

Could somebody please let me know how to make this control responsive for different views (Mobile, Desktop) and steps to do the same.

Thanks